# How to display a jQuery modal if only one of two radio two radio boxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery modal with the following HTML/jQuery codes:

Say I have a the following code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="subscription" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <form>
  <select> 
  <option value="1" checked> subscribe </option> 
  <option value="2"> unsubscribe </option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="choose" id="choose"> 
  </form>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('#choose').click(function () {
   // detect if unsubscribe is checked
   // pop up a dialog only if 'unsubscribe'  is chosen
})
```

My problem is showing a popup only if the unsubscribe is checked ad the button 'choose' is clicked.

Comment: One problem I see is that you don't have radio boxes, but a select input. So following this example you can use this selector to validate that unsuscribe is selected: `if ($('select').val() === 2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can only choose one option in your select ie. either Subscribe or Unsubscribe, a checkbox is redundant.A normal select will do.Then this should should be enough,

```
$('#choose').click(function () {
  if($("select").val() == 2)
    $('#modal').modal('show');
  else  
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```